# Custom html when inserting iframe TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm using a rich text field editor, so the user requires 0 HTML knowledge. In the backend, I will handle making the elements responsive by wrapping the necessary elements inside a div. The way TinyMce works is that you can press buttons to add chunks of HTML, like an image or iframe.
[image: TinyMCE]
At the top you can insert images and videos. My goal is to change that insert button so it wraps it with a div that makes it responsive.

I want to wrap an iframe with div so it becomes responsive. Let's say I add an iframe, I want to wrap that iframe with a div so it is made responsive. I have tried javascript, where it searches the doc for iframes and wraps them, but this seems unnecessarily complicated. Essentially I just want to change the button that inserts iframes to have a div around.

from

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/or1DfXdqu3U" width="560" height="314" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

to

```
<div class="ratio">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/or1DfXdqu3U" width="560" height="314" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
</div>
```

I found this, but unfortunately, I don't understand how this can be applied to what I am trying to do. But it does seem significant
http://archive.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=25649

Comment: Did you try this one? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_iframes.asp

Comment: @NipunaUpeksha That's, not the problem, the problem is adding the div to the inserted iframe. Remember I'm using a rich text field editor, so  I'm trying to edit the HTML that is inserted to provide that responsive div.

Comment: @NipunaUpeksha I want to apologise for my post not being clear about my situation, I have updated it to be more specific.